# Insert violates foreign key constraints

Tags: ruby, postgresql

My models:

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :objective
    belongs_to :consultancy
    has_one :seminar, :through => :consultancy

    belongs_to  :consultant, class_name: "Student"

    has_and_belongs_to_many  :users
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many  :teams
end
```

My function:

```
def find_placement(student)
    team = @consultancy.teams.detect{|x| x.has_room && student.objective_students.find_by(:objective => x.objective).obj_ready_and_willing?}
    team.users << student if team && team.valid? && team.persisted?
    return team
end
```

And this is the error I'm currently receiving:

```
PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: insert or update on table "teams_users" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_8299e376e9" DETAIL: Key (team_id)=(3396) is not present in table "teams". : INSERT INTO "teams_users" ("user_id", "team_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
```

This error only occurs in production environment, not development or testing. 
 I've tried using console mode to manually run each line of the function.  No error is triggered.

From this question https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29147/postgresql-insert-update-violates-foreign-key-constraints, I found this explanation.

*"If a new row is inserted, check DataID and Address: if they contain a non-NULL value (say 27856), then check Table1 for DataID˙and Table2 for Address. If there is no such value in those tables, then return an error."*

If I understand this paragraph correctly, my function is trying to insert a student into a team that doesn't exist.  But doesn't the "if team && team.valid? && team.persisted?" part of my code take care of that?  If not, what is a better way to insert the student into a team, but only if the team already exists.

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Comment: show your models and associations

Comment: Maybe that team exists in memory, but is not persisted (due to validation error or something). So it's enough to go past `if team`, but not enough for the database.

Comment: @ArupRakshit.  Ok.  Models and Associations added.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev.  If you're right, can I fix it with something like "if team && team.valid?"

Comment: @JeffZivkovic: you may try, at least. Won't hurt.

Comment: Try load a fresh resource, I mean instead of `@consultancy` use `team=fresh_consultancy.teams.detect.....`, where `fresh_consultancy=Consultancy.find(@consultancy.id)`. Maybe it doesn’t work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to getting past this was to reload.

Before, @consultancy was collecting all of the Teams, including some that had been destroyed.

```
@consultancy.reload.teams
```

only collects the teams that still exist.

I would not have come to this conclusion without the comment from @SergioTulentsev and the answer from @lacostenycoder.  Thanks!

Comment: glad you found the solution and we were able to help

Answer (score 1):

The `valid?` method does not check database persistence, so you may or maynot need it. You'll probably want to insure the `team` model is persisted and not deleted from the teams table. To be safe, you might check both.  [`ActiveRecord#persisted?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-persisted-3F) method:

```
def find_placement(student)
  if team = @consultancy.teams.detect{|x| x.has_room && student.objective_students.find_by(:objective => x.objective).obj_ready_and_willing?}
    team.users << student if team.valid? && team.persisted?
  end
  team
end
```

Comment: Hmmm.  I tried "team.users << student if team && team.valid? && team.persisted?".  Still getting the same error.  I updated my question to reflect this attempt.